# Main page (only that page) blank on deployed app

Tags: python, html, deployment

I have an app with multiple pages, running on python 2.7.
The app works just fine locally, but once I deployed it, the main page (with nothing after the slash) is completely blank after I log in on the login page that I created. I can type in the address to other pages in the app and they come up just fine (if I am logged in)

The URL is hoosierhillsfoodbank.blogspot.com
right now the only user is admin, admin.

There is a ton of code involved, so I'll only post what I think may be relevant. Here is the top of the HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Volunteer Kiosk | Home</title>
<link href="../static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

**Here is the code that makes the home page load after login**

```
class LoginPage(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        if self.session.get('user'):
            self.redirect('/') #already logged in, go to homepage
        else:
            doRender(self, 'login.html')

    def post(self):
        in_username = self.request.get('username')
        in_password = self.request.get('password')

        self.session['user'] = '' #logout user if still logged in
        if in_password == '' or in_username == '':
            doRender(self, 'login.html', 
                     {'error': 'Please specify Username and Password'})
            return

        result = User.all().filter('username =', in_username).get()

        if result and security.check_password_hash(in_password, result.password) :
            logging.info('session[user] ='+ self.session['user'])
            self.session['user'] = in_username
            self.session['usertype'] = result.usertype
            self.session['msg'] = 'Welcome '+self.session['user']
            self.redirect('/')
        else:
            doRender(self, 'login.html', 
                     {'error': 'Incorrect Username or Password'})
```

**Some more code that makes the "/" go to the home page**

```
def doRender(handler, tname='home.html', values={}):

    temp = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                    'templates/' + tname)
    if not os.path.isfile(temp):
        return False

    #make a copy of values and add the path
    newval = dict(values)
    newval['path'] = handler.request.path

    #check if user logged in
    val = handler.session.get('user')
    newval['user'] = val

    #if logged in, add userlinks
    if handler.session.get('user') and handler.session.get('usertype') < 2:
        newval['userlinks'] = [('/','Home'),
                             ('/Programs','Programs'),
                             ('/Volunteers','All Volunteers'),
                             ('/Individuals','Individuals'),
                             ('/ServiceLearners','Service Learners'),
                             ('/Groups','Groups'),]
        if handler.session.get('usertype') == 0:
            newval['userlinks'].append(('/users', 'Users'))

    #check if there's a msg, add it, then delete it
    newval['msg'] = handler.session.get('msg')
    handler.session['msg'] = ''

    handler.response.write(template.render(temp, newval))
    return True
```

**and of course, the handlers**

```
class MainPage(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        #check if logged in, otherwise redirect
        if self.session.get('user'):
            doRender(self, 'home.html')
        else:
            self.redirect('/login')

class Home(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.session.get('user'):
            time.sleep(.5)
            doRender(self, 'home.html')
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I know that it is probably strange that my code has both a mainpage and home handler, but getting rid of one of them did not help

Comment: Have you debug it at all? Any logged errors? If it works fine locally but not on the server, I would check those file paths for templates, or the DB setup if appropriate (or the way in which you save and check session data). Too many variables and too little information I think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The logs on the dashboard show no errors, just basic logs of me accessing the app.

Comment: It seems to work now. I think updating to the new SDK did the trick